# short description in shop page after title

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

hello i'm using this code in my functions.php file to display a short description in shop page (woocommerce page) but the discription goes before the title can some one help me please to display it after the title thank you

````
  if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
  } else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
  } 
  $excerpt = preg_replace('`[[^]]*]`','',$excerpt);
  return $excerpt;
}


function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description() {
    if ( has_excerpt() ) :
        ?>
        <div itemprop="description">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', excerpt(10) ) ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description', 5 );```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the wrong hook. You're using `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` but I believe you should be using `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` in your `add_action`.  See this code, this will add the short description after the title of your products on the shop page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_add_short_description' );
function wc_add_short_description() {
    global $product;

    ?>
        <div itemprop="description">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post-> post_excerpt ) ?>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: hello thank you but i still have the same problem even after using this code the discription goes befor the title.

Comment: @MaryamAit Can you be more clear which do you want to come first, the title or the description? On my test site this code puts the title first, then the short description

Comment: i need to put the title first then the short discription but i dont know why i have always the discription first